# Yet another Community Wiki oddity

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki

https://superuser.com/questions/16972/what-single-piece-of-software-do-you-most-admire-and-why/16990#16990

If my math is correct, (and I hope it is), if there are 3 people, each with one revision, then `(1 / 3) * 100 = 33.333...%`, not `36%`. I guess it's not a huge problem, but a bug nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

There's a style to how you should interpret the numbers on a community wiki post.

Our example:

> 3 revs, 2 users 36%
>   T Pops

There have been three revisions to the post.

Of those, they were made by two users in total (the first user in this case is excluded, having been deleted).

Of those, 36% of the bulk of editing/revisions has been done by the user T Pops.

Comment: +1 - It's based on the quantity of changes (characters added/deleted) and not how many edits there have been, I think is what @random is saying

Comment: Ah, so it's the *estimated* contribution, not the number of edits.